# IntelliJ + Corda: Error:(6, 30) java: package net.corda.testing.core does not exist

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin, corda

I'm a newbie using IntelliJ + Corda + Kotlin.

I just have installed IntelliJ IDEA, cloned the Corda Git Repository BootCamp (https://github.com/corda/bootcamp-cordapp), and the first thing that IntelliJ shows me are some Errors, claiming what I think are Kotlin packages and classes.

This are some of the Error messages:

Error:(6, 30) java: package net.corda.testing.core does not exist

Error:(12, 37) java: cannot find symbol

...symbol:   class TestIdentity

...location: class test.java.java_bootcamp.StateTests

```
package test.java.java_bootcamp;

import net.corda.core.contracts.ContractState;
import net.corda.core.identity.CordaX500Name;
import net.corda.core.identity.Party;
import net.corda.testing.core.TestIdentity;
import org.junit.Test;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

public class StateTests {

    private final Party alice = new TestIdentity(new CordaX500Name("Alice", "", "GB")).getParty();
    private final Party bob = new TestIdentity(new CordaX500Name("Bob", "", "GB")).getParty();

    @Test
    public void tokenStateHasIssuerOwnerAndAmountParamsOfCorrectTypeInConstructor() {
        new TokenState(alice, bob, 1);
    }

    @Test
    public void tokenStateImplementsContractState() {
        assert(new TokenState(alice, bob, 1) instanceof ContractState);
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong or missing?

BTW, I'm using a Mac

Answer (score 1):

After a 4 hour pain, I discovered that I need to add two JAR's, that solved my problem (for now).

These were them, from Maven Repository:

```
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.corda/corda-test-utils -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.corda</groupId>
        <artifactId>corda-test-utils</artifactId>
        <version>3.3-corda</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.corda/corda-node-driver -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.corda</groupId>
        <artifactId>corda-node-driver</artifactId>
        <version>3.3-corda</version>
    </dependency>
```